# How do I include a CA certificate trusted by Gmail into a Oracle Wallet?

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

Right now i'm working with oracle 11g on windows and currently trying to send notifications from my database using emails (Gmail), but all I'm clear with right now is that I have to include the Gmail certificate in the oracle wallets but don't know how to do it, and I also think that there's something to be done with the access control lists but I'm not completley sure how, any help or recommendations are enormously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any Windows users who may need help with what I asked, there's a really good link/tutorial sort of instruction set on git: 
https://github.com/YairPR/Oracle/wiki/Enviar-correo-con-Oracle:--ACL---UTL_SMTP---Wallet---SSL--TLS----Gmail 
It's in spanish, but all the commands and steps are there, although you may just happen to need to translate it, hope it's useful for someone!

Answer (score 2):

Backup the Oracle wallet files first. To get he wallet file locations run:

`SELECT * FROM V$ENCRYPTION_WALLET`

Then look at the `orapki` utility to get you started - search for this and you should find the Oracle documentation.

The following is how to add a certificate to the wallet:

`orapki wallet add -wallet wallet_location -trusted_cert -cert certificate_location`